# Detect when running time is near max_execution_time

Tags: php, execution-time

I want my script to detect when it's near the maximum execution time, so it can stop and update the database.

I know phpMyAdmin does something like this when importing large files, I just don't know how.

`register_shutdown_function()` won't work as far as I can tell. It will work when doing a simple `echo "test";`, but not when doing any database operation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

register_shutdown_function() can work... all instantiated object sare still present, but you need to make sure they're available in the scope of your shutdown callback function, which means you need to register the shutdown function **after** setting up your db connection, and pass the db connection as an argument to the callback function. The shutdown function is also called when the script terminates normally, or via a connection abort, so you need to ensure that you're not duplicating work that has already been done