# how to register a max execution limit in register_shutdown_function

Tags: php

When you register a function in `register_shutdown_function` how can you check for the error max execution time limit?

```
register_shutdown_function(function(){
    if(something)){
        // max execution time exceeded
    }
});
```

Comment: ..as well as this duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310375/detect-when-running-time-is-near-max-execution-time

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable in the start of script to get time script execution started and if you reach here `register_shutdown_function(function(){` calculate difference between that time and current time if it's greater than the time you have for execution(default 30 sec.) it's `max execution time limit` error

Answer (score 0):

You just have to get last error with `error_get_last()` and check if it says that maximum execution time exceeded.